# Need to write MDX for time dimension in Mondrian

Tags: olap, mdx

This is my Dimesion and Measure:

```
<Dimension type="TimeDimension" foreignKey="ReqDateKey" name="Date">
      <Hierarchy name="YQMD" hasAll="true" allMemberName="All Dates" primaryKey="date_id">
        <Table name="dim_date" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Year" column="year" parentColumn="date_entered" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="TimeYears">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Quarter" column="quarter" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeQuarters" captionColumn="quarter_label">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Month" column="month" type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" captionColumn="month_label">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="CountAutheticatedMedicine" column="DrugAuthCode" aggregator="count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
```

I have to find Measure in drill down fashion as per Year->Quarter->Month Hierarchy. I have only one year(2013) data. I have properly design my cube and it works for other dimensions but I stuck in time dimension. I refer [from here](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/07/a-simple-date-dimension-for-mondrian-cubes/) but couldn't find the right MDX.

Comment: Your question is not very clear; are you trying to understand how to use this dimension with your measures?